# Get new value on keypress

Tags: javascript, keyboard, onkeypress

How can I get the new value of input on keypress?

I got the following code:

```
checkfield = function(evt, textfield) {
    var newValue = \*put new value here*\;
    var myRegex = \*regex here*\
    if(!myRegex.test(newValue)) {
         theEvent.returnValue = false; 
         if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

I cannot use the keyup or keydown event because then `preventDefault` does not work.

I can read the unchanged value with `textfield.value` and I can read the new inserted character with

```
var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode( key );
```

It should not be too hard to combine the two in the correct way, but I don't know a good way to get the caret position within the keypress method without disabling `preventDefault`

Answer (score 1):

I got the following answer, might not be the best one but it works:

```
checkfield = function(evt, textfield) {
    var newValue = \*put new value here*\;
    var myRegex = \*regex here*\

    if(textfield.selectionStart === textfield.selectionEnd) {
            var caretPosition = textfield.selectionStart;
            var stringPart1 = textfield.value.substring(0, caretPosition);
            var stringPart2 = textfield.value.substring(caretPosition, textfield.value.length);
            newValue = stringPart1 + key + stringPart2;
        } else {
            var selectionStart = textfield.selectionStart;
            var selectionEnd = textfield.selectionEnd;
            var stringPart1 = textfield.value.substring(0, selectionStart);
            var stringPart2 = textfield.value.substring(selectionEnd, textfield.value.length);
            newValue = stringPart1 + key + stringPart2;
            console.log(newText);
        }
        if(!myRegex.test(newValue)) {
             theEvent.returnValue = false; 
             if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    if(!myRegex.test(newValue)) {
         theEvent.returnValue = false; 
         if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```